# Visual Studio: Static Link to Static Library

Tags: c++, mfc, linker, static-libraries

I've created a Static Library (no mfc is used in it) in Visual Studio and want to link with it in statically linked mfc project (com-dll actually).

When linking `mfc-lib` I get a bunch of messages `symbol is already defined`. This is because I linked standard C++ library twice (once in static library, and other in mfc project).

How do I fix it?
There is a workaround with `/FORCE:MULTIPLE`, but I think this is a bad decision.

Comment: The best way to fix it is to statically link all projects used, simple as that

Comment: Project + Properties, C/C++, Code Generation, Runtime Library setting.

Comment: Seems that problem really lies in difference of linking type. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When linking static libraries to a DLL or EXE project, you need to take care, that all projects have been compiled to use the same runtime library. So please set all projects to the same "Use of MFC" and also to the same "Runtime library". If you do not do so, then one project might have been compiled to take the fopen function from the standard CRT while another project might have been compiled to take the fopen function from the MFC. Mixing these is a problem for the linker because he does not know which runtime (and in the example: which fopen) to use.

When linking your DLL or EXE project against another DLL project, this is not a problem. You can have a DLL without MFC usage and link your MFC EXE against that DLL.

If you have a util library that you use very often in different projects, then you might consider setting up different build settings so you can build your library in DEBUG and RELEASE and with and without MFC. Then in your EXE project you can pick the library binary that matches your project settings.